# SQL query with muliple tables and results

Tags: sql

I have multiple tables that I need to link together. I used joins but I get duplicated results.

```
Table1.ID1
Table1.ID2 (Multiple Values)
Table2.Cost linked to Table1.ID2 (Multiple Values)
Table3.Qty linked to Table1.ID2 (Multiple Values)
Table4.AddCost linked to Table1.ID2 (Multiple Values)
Where Table1.ID1 = 'Unique1'
```

What I have is:

```
Select 
    Table1.ID1, Table1.ID2, 
    Sum(Table2.Cost), Sum(Table3.QTY), Sum(Table4.AddCost)
From 
    Table1
inner join 
    Table2 on Table2.ID2 = Table1.ID2
Inner Join 
    Table3 on Table3.ID2 = Table2.ID2
Inner Join 
    Table4 on Table4.ID2 = Table2.ID2
Where 
    Table1.ID1 = 'Unique1'
Group by 
    Table1.ID1, Table1.ID2
Order by 
    Table1.ID2
```

The problem is, `Table1.ID2` has multiple values matching `Table1.ID1`. Table2,3, and 4 are transaction tables and I want to SUM each transaction that matches `Table1.ID2`.

I was thinking of using a For Each loop, but I hear loops shouldn't be used in SQL.

The end result I'm looking for is this:

```
'Table1.ID2 'A' | Sum table2 | Sum Table3 | Sum Table4 (Where Table2,3,4 = Table1.ID2 'A'; and where Table1.ID1 = 'Unique1')
'Table1.ID2 'B' | Sum table2 | Sum Table3 | Sum Table4 (Where Table2,3,4 = Table1.ID2 'B'; and where Table1.ID1 = 'Unique1')
'Table1.ID2 'C' | Sum table2 | Sum Table3 | Sum Table4 (Where Table2,3,4 = Table1.ID2 'C'; and where Table1.ID1 = 'Unique1')
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have any linking between tables 2, 3, and 4, so the query is effectively cross-joining them.

It seems like the result you want needs to be done with sub-queries:

```
Select T1.ID1, T1.ID2, T2.Cost, T3.QTY, T4.AddCost
From Table1 T1
inner join (SELECT ID2, SUM(Cost) Cost FROM Table2 GROUP BY ID2) T2
on T2.ID2 = T1.ID2
Inner Join (SELECT ID2, SUM(QTY) QTY FROM Table3 GROUP BY ID2) T3
on T3.ID2 = T1.ID2
Inner Join (SELECT ID2, SUM(AddCost) AddCost FROM Table4 GROUP BY ID2) T4
on T4.ID2 = T1.ID2
Where T1.ID1 = 'Unique1'
Order by T1.ID2
```

or by inlining the subqueries:

```
Select 
    T1.ID1,
    T1.ID2,
    (SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM Table2 WHERE ID2 = T1.ID2) Cost,
    (SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM Table3 WHERE ID2 = T1.ID2) QTY,
    (SELECT SUM(AddCost) FROM Table4 WHERE ID2 = T1.ID2) AddCost
FROM Table1 T1
Where T1.ID1 = 'Unique1'
Order by T1.ID2
```

Comment: I tried both your suggestions. The first one has errors about not being able to find the T2.Cost, T3.QTY and T4. ADDcost.


The Inline one, threw errors at Line 5 and 6, about the ' ) QTY'  and ') addCost' It also can't find the T1.ID2 in each inline subquery.

Comment: @Kevin I had a few typos that have been corrected.  See if the current versions work better for you,

Comment: Yes, This worked. Thanks. The Sub query one, I had to add a From Table1 after the Addcost. But other than that. It works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Kevin - I have corrected that as well.  Glad it worked for you.

Comment: I have another question about this same query. It turns out I need to a sum of a sum. I know this isn't possible and I've tried several things but still cannot seem to get it right. Could you help me out again, if you don't mind. 

On Table 3 I need to pull `Sum((T3.QTY * T6.Cost) where T3.ID3 = T6.ID3)` Do you have any thoughts? I've exhausted my resources the past couple hours with no avail.

Comment: @Kevin you'd be better off asking that as a separate question - you'll get more responses and better answers,